# Extend Laravel project model from within a package

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a Laravel based projected called **Akaunting**.

In the project it has models, for example they have a model `App\Models\Banking\Account`

I am trying to make a `Package`, and I have access only to add code into my `Package` (cannot edit files in the main Laravel project.

How can I extend the `App\Models\Banking\Account` model so that it has some additional methods; so that everywhere in the project where the `App\Models\Banking\Account` model is used the project will have access to my added methods.

Currently the only way I have been able to do this is by using `class_alias` to completely replace the original model with my own custom model by adding this to my `register()` method in my package service provider:

```
class_alias('Modules\BankingSortCode\Models\Account', 'App\Models\Banking\Account');
```

But this means that I have to copy the entire contents of `App\Models\Banking\Account` into my new customized model at `Modules\BankingSortCode\Models\Account`

The problem with this is that if the original project updates their `App\Models\Banking\Account` model then anyone running my package would not be using the updated model (and potentially break the whole site)

I want to be able to just extend the original model, but if I try doing that i get an Exception that I'm trying to re-declare `App\Models\Banking\Account`  (see example of what I want to be able to do below):

```
<?php
namespace Modules\BankingSortCode\Models;

class Account extends \App\Models\Banking\Account {
    public function getSortCodeFormatAttribute(){
        return implode("-", str_split($this->bank_sort_code, 2));
    }

}
```

Comment: they will have to adjust their models, their models would extend or include your functionality

Comment: The project you are using doesn't support the change of a model. It should be somewhere in the config files but I could not find it. According to the docs you could create your own module:
https://akaunting.com/docs/developer-manual/modules
Within the module you can create and use you own models and they can extend their models. However you cannot change the base functionality in the way that you are describing.